# Single quotes in SQL in a Query Object inside of cfscript in a ColdFusion component

Tags: coldfusion, hql, cfc

A bit of a confusing title, but I'll try to be clear here. When using the query object inside of `<cfscript>` and you have some sql in the form:

```
 SELECT city + ', ' + state + ' ' + zip as Address2
 FROM users WHERE user_id = :userid
```

ColdFusion will error out. `:userid` is the parameter that I added using `addParam` and the query works perfectly when I remove the `' '` between state and zip. For some reason adding that space is causing the query object go out of whack and it gives me incorrect syntax near the `:` symbol.

This query also works fine when I simply use `<cfquery>`, but I would like to use it in `<cfscript>`. Any ideas? Is this a bug? or am I missing something?

Edit: I'm using Coldfusion 9, MS SQL 2005 and this is being done inside of a CFC with the cfscript syntax. Like so:

```
component
{
  public function getAgent(member_id)
  {
    qryAgent = new query(dataSource="Members");
    qryAgent.setName("get_agent");
    qryAgent.addParam(name="memberid",value=member_id,cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER");

    result = qryAgent.execute(sql="SELECT FirstName, LastName, FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName FROM Member m WHERE m.member_id = :memberid");
    return result.getResult();
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but is your query in a string that is surrounded by single quotes, either escape the inner quotes or change the outer quotes to double quotes?

Comment: Are all 3 of these columns of the same type? All char or varchar()?

Comment: Yes they are. Again when I remove the + ' ', everyting works perfectly.

Comment: Which database? MySQL? SQL Server? Which ColdFusion version? It's a good idea to include this info with each question.

Comment: ColdFusion 9, MS SQL 2005. I'll edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding an extra space in your + ' ' + .... just for me  :)

Comment: I did that too didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging and finding the answer I found that someone else had already found this here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/683656?tstart=-4 and adobe has fixed it in CF 9.0.1

The problem comes in the query.cfc file that is in the folder ColdFusion9\CustomTags\com\adobe\coldfusion\query.cfc. The replaceDelimsWithMarkers function has a call to listtoarray (line 346 in my version). This call doesn't have the 3rd argument includeEmptyFields set to true which is causing my sql string to get mangled.

This can be manually fixed by adding the third argument of true.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax, from the code that is posted, looks solid for MS SQL. I ran the following test on my local box with ACF 9 and MS SQL Server 2008 installed (I know you're on 2005 but it should be identical for something like string concatenation).

```
<cfscript>
    qry = new query();
    qry.setDatasource("mydsn");
    qry.setName("myqry");
    qry.addParam(name="userid",value="3735",cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
    result = qry.execute(sql="SELECT firstname + ' ' + lastname AS fullname FROM mydb where userid = :userid");
    writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

Running this in a browser returns a "fullname" value that is correctly concatenated.

By chance, does this code snippet help uncover anything unusual in your full cfscript query? If not, is it possible for you to post more of your code as it relates to setting up the query service?

EDIT: I also ran it with the following 'result =' expression to make it more like the concatenation you're doing:

```
result = qry.execute(sql="SELECT firstname + ', ' + lastname + ' ' + email AS fullname FROM mydb where userid = :userid");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I minimized my query to test exactly what's causing the error and I found that if I remove the argument, :userid, then everything works or if I remove the ' ', then everything works fine. Both together are not working. I'm using the second syntax that you posted. Also my CF9 build is 9,0,0,251028. Don't know if that has anything to do with it

Comment: I failed to mention that this is being done in a CFC maybe that has something to do with it. I have edited my question to reflect his.

Comment: @derickito I figured it was in a CFC so no worries! I just created a similar table (Member with columns for FirstName, LastName and member_number). I then added some dummy data and ran your query as provided above. Everything worked perfectly. You mentioned in the original post that ColdFusion would "error" out. Can you post some form of the error message? EDIT: I am on ACF 9.0.1 but I don't recall any details of this sort of update in 9.0.1 but will check.

Comment: I found the issue and I just added an answer. It turns out that the 9,0,0,251028 build has this issue so you'll never be able to replicate it since it was fixd in 9,0,1. Thanks none the less

Comment: Just saw the same as I was researching it :). Glad you at least found the cause!